# Spring Boot Test Fails in Eclipse but passes on command line (failed to load ApplicationContext because of Null PropertyResolver)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, spring-boot

I have jumped on a pre-existing project that has a Spring JUnit test that cannot successfully execute from inside Eclipse, but it runs on the command line when I execute `mvn clean install`. I would really like to be able to execute my test from inside of Eclipse so that I can easily remote debug my Spring application under the right conditions. I have tried Googling and searching for pre-existing StackOverflow questions but surprisingly nobody seems to have my stack trace.

The gist of the stack trace is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PropertyResolver must not be null
...
```

How can I get my test using the `@SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` and `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` annotations to work both from inside Eclipse and on the command line? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Please note that I am using:

1. Java 1.8
2. Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
3. Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE
4. Spring 4.2.3.RELEASE
5. JUnit 4.12

My Java test class is as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MyApplication.class})
public class MyTest {

  // This test is extremely simplistic. I commented out everything I could
  // in Eclipse where I am still able to reproduce the problem.

  @Test
  public void passMe() {
    // pass this test :)
  }
}
```

The code for `MyApplication` is as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource({"classpath:myservice.props", "classpath:myclient.props"})
public class MyApplication {
  private static final Logger LOG =
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApplication.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app =
        new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
    app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.LOG);
    app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.CONSOLE);
    ApplicationContext ctx = app.run(args);

    if (LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
      LOG.trace("Application Name:", ctx.getApplicationName());
      LOG.trace("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");
      String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
      Arrays.sort(beanNames);
      for (String beanName : beanNames) {
        LOG.trace(beanName);
      }
    }
  }

  //To resolve ${} in @Value
  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfig() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void finalizeExit() {
    LOG.warn("Application exiting...");
    if (LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
      DumpEndpoint dump = new DumpEndpoint();
      LOG.trace("thread dump info: {}", dump.invoke());
    }
    ShutdownEndpoint shutdown = new ShutdownEndpoint();
    LOG.warn("Shutingdown gracefully...");
    shutdown.invoke();
  }
}
```

The `myservice.props` and and `myclient.props` files are in the `src/main/resources` folder of the Maven project. Also, I have explicitly added the `src/main/resources` folder to the classpath of the test's run configuration but to no avail.

The *complete* stack trace that I am getting when I run `MyTest` from Eclipse is as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PropertyResolver must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver.<init>(RelaxedPropertyResolver.java:42)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.getExcludeAutoConfigurationsProperty(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:165)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.getExclusions(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:152)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:80)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:328)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:233)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:154)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:131)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:225)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:154)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:140)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:282)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
... 25 more
```

Thanks again for your help.

Edit: The exception is happening because the `EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector` class has a null `environment` field, which it is passing to the constructor of `RelaxedPropertyResolver`. I tried passing the `-Dspring.profiles.active=development` system variable in the run configuration from Eclipse but that resulted in the same stack trace.

Comment: Different behavior between Eclipse and Maven CLI is frequently because Eclipse does not have properly separated test and compile classpaths. Check the autoconfiguration report to see whether Eclipse is mistakenly including something it shouldn't, maybe from a workspace dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @chrylis. Your comment led me down the path eventually led to a solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the problem turned out to be because my project in Eclipse depended on downstream project. When I went into my project's build path and removed the downstream project, my test went from red to green.

The difference was spotted by contrasting output from the correct Maven CLI execution and the incorrect Eclipse execution. By diff'ing command line output between Maven CLI and Eclipse I spotted the following line in the Maven CLI console output:

```
<org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver><main><org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingJarResources(?:?):Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/Users/jthoms/.m2/repository/com/acme/teamnamespace/downstream-project/0.0.2/downstream-project-0.0.2.jar]>
```

This corresponded to a line in Eclipse's console output:

```
<org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver><main><org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindMatchingFileSystemResources(?:?):Looking for matching resources in directory tree [/git/cloned/downstream-project/target/classes/com/acme/teamnamespace]>
```

In the Maven CLI output the source from a JAR file but in Eclipse it was in a project directory tree. After that line, all logged output started to become very different until the exception occurred.

Answer (score -1):

Check that the class name ends with "Test", otherwise maven will just skip the tests in that class and that's confusing you. Eclipse JUnit doesn't care about the class name and runs it anyway